# Width of menu not proper in menu bar

Tags: html, css

I have set the width of each element in the menu to be 25% (totaling 100%). See code below:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Epsilon Eridani Project</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<!--page header-->

 <h1>Epsilon Eridani Project</h1>

<!--menu-->
<table width="100%" bgcolor="white" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4">
<tr>
<td width="25%">
  <img src="images/s-logo.jpg" alt=" " height="40" width="60"/>
  <span class="menu">Home</span></td>
<td width="25%">
<td width="25%">
  <img src="images/s-logo.jpg" alt=" " height="40" width="60"/>
  <span class="menu">Eridanus</span></td>
<td width="25%">
<td width="25%">
  <img src="images/s-logo.jpg" alt=" " height="40" width="60"/>
  <span class="menu">Latest News</span></td>
<td width="25%">
<td width="25%">
  <img src="images/s-logo.jpg" alt=" " height="40" width="60"/>
  <span class="menu">Community</span></td>
<td width="25%">
</tr>
</table>
</html>
```

However, in the output, it looks very messed up. [See output in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PauWG.jpg)

I am confused as to why this is happening? Thank you for your time.

Comment: this is a styling issue, not a php one which you tagged as. Why? I don't know.

Comment: what *was* it supposed to look like? you never said what the problem is and what the final result should look like.

Comment: Tables should be used for tabular data only - not for layouts. Use `<div>` elements instead and style them how you want with CSS.

Comment: The syntax of your HTML markup is totally incorrect. Use HTML markup validators to check it first.

Comment: Stop using tables for design, use CSS.

Comment: plus the title needs to reflect the problem.

Comment: Yes, I am changing this now but i was curious as to why this had happened. I am using the <div> to create a fixed menu. I was just curious as to why something like this would happen.

Comment: The error is due to unclosed `<td>`. Use `flex` instead of using width in percentage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few

```
 <td width="25%">
```

That don't have a closing `</td>`

It's also good practice to indent your code, it will make it easier to find the issues.

```
<table width="100%" bgcolor="white" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4">
  <tr>
    <td width="25%">
      <img src="images/s-logo.jpg" alt=" " height="40" width="60"/>
      <span class="menu">Home</span>
    </td>
    <td width="25%"></td>  <!-- Should this be here??  --> 
    <td width="25%">
      <img src="images/s-logo.jpg" alt=" " height="40" width="60"/>
      <span class="menu">Eridanus</span>
    </td>
    <td width="25%"></td>  <!-- Should this be here??  -->
    <td width="25%">
      <img src="images/s-logo.jpg" alt=" " height="40" width="60"/>
      <span class="menu">Latest News</span>
    </td>
    <td width="25%"></td>  <!-- Should this be here??  -->
    <td width="25%">
      <img src="images/s-logo.jpg" alt=" " height="40" width="60"/>
      <span class="menu">Community</span>
    </td>
    <td width="25%"></td>  <!-- Should this be here??  -->
  </tr>
</table>
```

I hope this puts you on the right track to solve your problem. :)

Comment: Thank you so much. I just curious as what could cause an output like that. =)

Comment: Glad I could help. :)